# Google Script - Change Format of Link in email

Tags: google-apps-script, text, hyperlink

I would like to change the format of the link to not include the whole link; but an embedded link in text:

```
   var message = "TSR # " + TSRNumberVal + " for " + "Tank Code: " + TankCodeVal + " at " + 
   CustomerVal + " in " + CityVal + " " + StateVal + " ( " + RegionVal + " ) " + "is now Closed" +'\n' 
   +'\n' + "Link to TSR Database: " + 
   "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPKpk6rZrvc0XkejF_xzhUofIECSJM2euqQrjqlJ8G0/edit? 
   usp=xxxx"
```

To display: "TSR Database Link" with the link embedded in the text.

How do I correct this?

Thank you!
~Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying `message` as a value in a cell in Google Spreadsheet, then do this:

```
var url = 'www.google.com'// your full url`

var text = 'Go to Google'

var cell = ... // the cell that you are inserting this value into`

cell.setFormula("=HYPERLINK(\"" + url + "\", \"" + text + "\")")
```

If you want to display `message` as text in an email (per your comment), do this:

```
var recipient = 'someone1@somewhere.com, someone2@somewhere.com, someone3@somewhere.com'// your email recipients separated by commas
var url = 'www.google.com' // put your actual url here
var subject = 'your email subject subject'
var textToDisplay = 'TSR Database Link'
var body = "<a href=\""+ url + "\">" + textToDisplay + "</a>"
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, { htmlBody: body });
```

[Google App Script's Mail APP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) lets you send emails in HTML format, passing an optional options object as the 4th parameter to MailApp.sendEmail. To create a hyperlink in html, you need to use an [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: here's the code:  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddy + "," + SenderEmail, "NO-REPLY@xxxx.com", subject, message);  where Message is the code above.  I want the messge to not display the whole hyperlink; but Text with embedded URL

Comment: But that first parameter takes a list of email address separated by commas.  Not embedded urls.

Comment: @JasonG the first parameter that MailApp.sendEmail accepts is represented by `recipient`. As you can see in the code sample, recipient is an email address, not an embedded URL.

Comment: You can set `recipient` to whichever email address(es) you want to. The url will appear embedded in text in the email body because of the html formatting in the `body` variable. When you provide a third options argument to `sendEmail()` you can set the `htmlBody` property equal to an html formatted string. In this case, the html formatted string that I provided embeds your url in the text that you provide.

Comment: @RayGun my mail script is : MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddy, "NO-REPLY@Airgas.com", subject, message); 
where var message = "TSR # " + TSRNumberVal + " for " + "Tank Code: " + TankCodeVal + " at " + CustomerVal + " in " + CityVal + " " + StateVal + " ( " + RegionVal + " ) " + "is now Closed" +'\n' +'\n' + "Link to TSR Database: " + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/" +'\n' +'\n' + '\n' + "Please do not reply to this email, it is a non-monitored email address!";   I just need to get the link to display as text with embedded code

Comment: @JasonG to get the link to display as a hyperlink (as text with the link embedded in the text), you need to send the text in HTML format. The code that I gave you does that. If you have multiple email addresses that you want to assign as `recipient`, then set `recipient = 'emailAddress1, emailAddress2, emailAdress3, ...'`

Comment: I got it!  THANK YOU @RayGun